# Detecting Wi-Fi network changes while app is running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, network-programming

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507756/getting-reachability-changed-notifications-in-the-background?rq=1) which has no answer since 2011, which suggest to use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) apple sample code in order to detect from an iOS app when the **network has changed** (whilst running in the background).

I need to be able to do so while the app is in background, but the sample of code has nothing showing background execution.

Any idea on how I can do this?

This is the AppDelegate code I wrote so far:

```
#import "APLAppDelegate.h"
//#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation APLAppDelegate
@synthesize reachability;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Initialize Reachability


    //Reachability *

    reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

    return YES;
}


- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    // Start Monitoring
    [reachability startNotifier];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];

}
```

Comment: check this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299

Comment: I used it before but doesn't explain much on checking this whilst in background..

Comment: @mm24 did you find a solution for this? I am using NSURLSessionConfiguration Downloadtask and need to cancel it when there is a network disconnection in the background. I need to get the network changes notification in the background hence I can cancel the request.